# Liquibase: how to load date fields from CSV?

Tags: timestamp, liquibase

I'm on a Spring-Boot project and I'm using Liquibase in order to populate the DB from CSV files. Among them, there are some entities with date fields.

Here is my databaseChangelog for creating the table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity Container.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20180424154826-1" author="jhipster">
        <createTable tableName="container">
            <column name="id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
                <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>

            <column name="description" type="varchar(2000)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <column name="container_type" type="varchar(255)">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <column name="created" type="timestamp">
                <constraints nullable="true" />
            </column>

            <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
        </createTable>
        <dropDefaultValue tableName="container" columnName="created" columnDataType="datetime"/>

    </changeSet>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changeset - JHipster will add changesets here, do not remove-->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And here the changelog for populating the Table:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

    <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

    <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

    <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
    <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>

    <!--
        Added the entity ExternalAudit.
    -->
    <changeSet id="20180425154950-1" author="developer">
        <loadData catalogName="container"
                  encoding="UTF-8"
                  file="config/liquibase/containers.csv"
                  schemaName="public"
                  separator=";"
                  quotchar="'"
                  tableName="container">
        </loadData>
    </changeSet>
    <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changeset - JHipster will add changesets here, do not remove-->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

And in the end the CSV containing the data for the table:

```
id;name;description;container_type;created
1;'Human';'Human container';'HUMAN';${now}
2;'IT';'IT container';'IT';${now}
3;'Physical';'Physical container';'PHYSICAL';${now}
4;'Intangible';'Intangible container';'INTANGIBLE';${now}
```

The problem is that if I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

I get the following log in the console, complaining about the date field:

```
nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:297)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180425154950_added_Containers_data.xml::20180425154950-1::developer:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') -- ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}') [22007-197] [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO public.container (id, name, description, container_type, created) VALUES ('1', 'Human', 'Human container', 'HUMAN', '${now}')]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:619)
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:51)
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:79)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:214)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:94)
    at io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1688)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

While if I run:

```
mvn process-resources
mvn liquibase:update
```

the result is a **BUILD SUCCESS**

Comment: I don't know if that will work, but try to add nested element to`<loadData>` that will be your column. Something like this: `<column name="created" value="${now}"/>` Maybe you should use `valueComputed` attribute. Just read [this page](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/column.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your csv just use `now` instead of `${now}`. Then it should not throw `Cannot parse "TIMESTAMP" constant "${now}";` any more